# In which situations, the elements will be attached to Head element of DOM during HTML parsing?

Tags: html, dom, html-parsing, html-parser

Obviously, the contents/tags within `<head></head>` pair will be attached to Head element.

Is there any situation in which during the parsing of `<body></body>`, some elements would be attached to Head element, instead of Body element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the HTML5 parsing algorithm, no, except via injection by script. Some older browsers may move such elements though. For example see the thread that starts at http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-html/2007May/1066.html and in particular http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-html/2007May/1081.html

However, there is the case of what happens to an element that's normally in head, appears either before the `<head>` tag, or after the `</head>` tag but before the body element is created, for instance [http://software.hixie.ch/...](http://software.hixie.ch/utilities/js/live-dom-viewer/?%3C!DOCTYPE%20html%3E%0A%3Chtml%3E%0A%3Chead%3E%0A%20%3Ctitle%3ETest%20Case%3C%2Ftitle%3E%0A%3C%2Fhead%3E%0A%3Cmeta%20name%3D%22ROBOTS%22%20content%3D%22ALL%22%3E%0A%3C%2Fhead%3E%0A%3Cbody%3E%0A%3Cp%3EMy%20text%3C%2Fp%3E%0A%3C%2Fbody%3E%0A%3C%2Fhtml%3E). In this situation, the element will be moved inside the head element.

Note that elements between the `<head>` and `</head>` tags can easily end up not inside the head element due to invalid mark up, for instance, [http://software.hixie.ch/...](http://software.hixie.ch/utilities/js/live-dom-viewer/?%3C!DOCTYPE%20html%3E%0A%3Chtml%3E%0A%3Chead%3E%0A%20%3Ctitle%3ETest%20Case%3C%2Ftitle%3E%0A%20%3Chr%3E%0A%20%3Cmeta%20name%3D%22ROBOTS%22%20content%3D%22ALL%22%3E%0A%3C%2Fhead%3E%0A%3Cbody%3E%0A%3Cp%3EMy%20text%3C%2Fp%3E%0A%3C%2Fbody%3E%0A%3C%2Fhtml%3E)